# How can I use an appSetting parameter (located in web.config) in my .master template

Tags: razor, razor-2

appSetting parameters
I have a value within app settings that I would like to use in my master page file but I think I am using the wrong syntax. Please bear with me because I am very new to Umbraco

My Web.config code is

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="7829e" />
</appSettings>
```

The code within my master page is

```
    <umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
        @AppSetting.myKey
    </umbraco:Macro>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not Umbraco related at all, you should be able to do

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]
```

Just like you would in standard ASP.NET.

Comment: when I use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] in my .master page nothing shows

Comment: You're replacing "key" with whatever the name of your setting is, right? "myKey" in your example? Also, if you are using an actual master page (.master), you can't use Razor syntax. Try <%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"] %> instead. Which Umbraco version is this, BTW?

Comment: Yes I'm replacing "Key" with the name I'm using